# Converting a pointer to 64-bit integer, why is the result different on 32-bit & 64-bit platform

Tags: c

I have a code snippet(up.cpp) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long Uint64;
int main()
{
    void *p = (void*)0xC0001234;
    Uint64 u64 = (Uint64)p;
    printf("{%llx}\n", u64);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with 32-bit gcc 4.8.1, I get output:

```
{ffffffffc0001234}
```

Compiling it with 64-bit gcc 4.8.1, I get output:

```
{c0001234}
```

Yes, the 64-bit one gives the 32-bit value. The gcc 4.8.1 is from openSUSE 13.1 .

I also tried it on Visual C++ 2010 x86 & x64 complier(a bit code change, `__int64` and `%I64x`), and surprising get the same results.

Of course, I intend to get `{c0001234}` on both x86 & x64. But why is there such difference?

Comment: Because your using "ll" and not "llu".

Comment: @barakmanos: He is using `%llx` where the `x` means both unsigned and hexadecimal.

Comment: But finally I want to control output flavor, `"%llx"` will give me 'abcdef' while `"%llX"` will give me 'ABCDEF'.

Comment: This question is tagged `c` but the filename ends in `.cpp` and you say you're compiling with Visual C++ but you also mention gcc. Are you compiling this as a C or C++ program?

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of this

```
Uint64 u64 = (Uint64)p;
```

is not defined by the language. It is implementation-defined.

While 64-bit platforms will probably implement this as purely conceptual conversion (the pointer "fills" the entire target value), on 32-bit platforms implementations are faced with a dilemma: how to extend a 32-bit pointer value to a 64-bit integer value, with sign-extension or without? Apparently, your implementations decided to sign-extend the value.

Apparently your implementations believe that in a pointer-to-unsigned conversion the original pointer value should act as a *signed* value of sorts. This would be a rather strange decision though. I cannot reproduce it in GCC: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9089ccda625bd65d

If that's really what happens on your platform, you should be able to suppress this behavior by converting to `uintptr_t` first (as an intermediate type), as suggested by @barak manos in the comments.

Comment: Probably `uintptr_t` will solve this platform-dependency (though I'm not sure that the C-language standard defines it).

Comment: Of course it should do unsigned extend. It's so weird to imagine a pointer could be negative.

Comment: @JimmChen: The AMD64 memory model is divided into a lower half (user space, addresses starting with 0000) and an upper half (kernel space, addresses starting with FFFF).  Viewed as signed integers, these are positive and negative, respectively.

Comment: OK. That's a good insight. But this idea does not apply to 32-bit systems, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, OP's demo code failed to connivingly show the value of the pointer, nor its size.  Should have also had `printf("%p %zu\n", p, sizeof p);`.